# Swift MessageKit problems - running swift 4.2

Tags: swift, messagekit

I had just updated my code to swift 4.2 and fixed all the errors. Now I am trying to use 'MessageKit' to put a messenger into my app. Everything is updated yet I am having these problems... now it is saying for `MessagesInputBarDelegate`

> "Use of undeclared type 'MessagesInputBarDelegate'"

and

> "Use of undeclared type 'MessageInputBar'"

Also,

> "Argument Labels '(type:)' do not match any available overloads"

and

> "Cannot convert value of type'_?' to expected argument type 'URL?"

**Use of undeclared type 'MessagesInputBarDelegate'**

**Use of undeclared type 'MessageInputBar'**

```
extension CustomerChatViewController: MessagesInputBarDelegate {

func messageInputBar(_ inputBar: MessageInputBar, didPressSendButtonWith text: String) {
    let message = Message(user: user, content: text)

    save(message)
    inputBar.inputTextView.text = ""
}

}
```

**Argument labels '(type:)' do not match any available overloads**

```
let cameraItem = UIBarButtonItem(type: .system)
```

**Cannot convert value of type '_?' to expected argument type 'URL?'**

```
let imageName = [UUID().uuidString, String(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)].joined()
    storage.child(channelID).child(imageName).putData(data, metadata: metadata) { meta, error in
        completion(meta?.downloadURL())
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you install **MessageInputBar** ? You can install it like that

```
pod 'MessageInputBar'
```

Since **MessageKit 2.0.0** you have to install **MessageInputBar**

Comment: If the `MessageInputBar` pod is required to use the `MessageKit` pod, it seems like the podspec of `MessageKit` should be updated to reflect that dependency. Manually adding a dependency to your own `Podfile` seems like a workaround rather than a real solution.

Comment: @DávidPásztor you're right, I'll take a look at this more closely

Comment: Hi there, I'm doing the review rounds and I see you want to remove the `MessageData` part from the question. Why, is it unrelated to the other errors in the question? Next time just comment to the author and ask them to remove it!

Comment: The error of message data cames because of a wrong import of another module. In addition there are another stack overflow post for that

Comment: For Carthage users, include this in your Cartfile: `github "MessageKit/MessageInputBar"`

Answer (score 3):

adding worked for me too then

```
import InputBarAccessoryView
```

then in viewDidLoad() add this :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        messageInputBar.delegate = self
        maintainPositionOnKeyboardFrameChanged = true
        messageInputBar.inputTextView.tintColor = .yellow
        messageInputBar.sendButton.setTitleColor(.purple, for: .normal)


        messagesCollectionView.messagesDataSource = self
        messagesCollectionView.messagesLayoutDelegate = self
        messagesCollectionView.messagesDisplayDelegate = self
        messagesCollectionView.messageCellDelegate = self

        messageInputBar.leftStackView.alignment = .center
        messageInputBar.setLeftStackViewWidthConstant(to: 50, animated: false)

    }
```

calling the delegate method :

```
extension ChatVC: MessageInputBarDelegate {

    func inputBar(_ inputBar: InputBarAccessoryView, didPressSendButtonWith text: String) {
        guard let user = self.user else{return}
        guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else{return}
        let ref = Database.database().reference().child("messages").child(uid).child("personal").child(user.uid)
        let values = ["sender": uid, "text": text, "recipient": user.uid]
        ref.updateChildValues(values)
        inputBar.inputTextView.text = ""
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well i also added this in the view controller class

`import MessageInputBar`